# Как вывести из цикла foreach в конец строки

Tags: php, foreach

```
    $data = [
        'authors' => [
            301 => [
                'id' => 301,
                'name' => 'Александр Сергеевич Пушкин',
                'email' => 'alexander_pushkin@example.com',
                'birthYear' => 1799,
            ],
            10 => [
                'id' => 10,
                'name' => 'Николай Васильевич Гоголь',
                'email' => 'nikolay_gogol@example.com',
                'birthYear' => 1809,
            ],
            17 => [
                'id' => 17,
                'name' => 'Михаил Юрьевич Лермонтов',
                'email' => 'mikhail_lermontov@example.com',
                'birthYear' => 1814,
            ],
        ],
        'books' => [
            [
                'title' => 'Евгений Онегин',
                'publishedAt' => '1823—1832',
                'author' => 301,
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Полтава',
                'publishedAt' => '1828—1829',
                'author' => 301,
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Мёртвые души',
                'publishedAt' => '1842',
                'author' => 10,
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Сказка о рыбаке и рыбке',
                'publishedAt' => '1833',
                'author' => 301,
    
            ],
        ],
    ];
echo '=== Книги ===<br>';

foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    foreach ($value as $key2 =>$value2){

        // echo "[$key2]", $value2, "<br>";
        foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3){

            if($key3 == 'title'){
                echo $value3 ." - ";
            }
              
            elseif($key3 == 'author' and $value3 == 301){
                echo "Александр Сергеевич Пушкин" ." - ". "<br>";
            }
            elseif($key3 == 'author' and $value3 == 10){
                echo "Николай Васильевич Гоголь" ." - ". "<br>";
            }
            elseif($key3 == 'publishedAt'){
                echo $value3;
            }

    }
    
}

};
```

Выводит:
Евгений Онегин - 1823—1832 Александр Сергеевич Пушкин -
Полтава - 1828—1829 Александр Сергеевич Пушкин -
Мёртвые души - 1842 Николай Васильевич Гоголь -
Сказка о рыбаке и рыбке - 1833 Александр Сергеевич Пушкин -

Как вывести "publishedAt" в конец строки, чтобы получилось

Евгений Онегин - Александр Сергеевич Пушкин -1823—1832
Полтава -Александр Сергеевич Пушкин -1828—1829 
Мёртвые души - Николай Васильевич Гоголь -1842
Сказка о рыбаке и рыбке - Александр Сергеевич Пушкин -1833

Оставлю здесь

```
foreach ($data['books'] as $book){


        echo $book['title']. '-'. $data['authors'][$book['author']]['name']. '-'. $book['publishedAt']. '<br>';


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом, вам достаточно одного `foreach`.

```php
<?php

$data = [
    'authors' => [
        301 => [
            'id' => 301,
            'name' => 'Александр Сергеевич Пушкин',
            'email' => 'alexander_pushkin@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1799,
        ],
        10 => [
            'id' => 10,
            'name' => 'Николай Васильевич Гоголь',
            'email' => 'nikolay_gogol@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1809,
        ],
        17 => [
            'id' => 17,
            'name' => 'Михаил Юрьевич Лермонтов',
            'email' => 'mikhail_lermontov@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1814,
        ],
    ],
    'books' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Евгений Онегин',
            'publishedAt' => '1823—1832',
            'author' => 301,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Полтава',
            'publishedAt' => '1828—1829',
            'author' => 301,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Мёртвые души',
            'publishedAt' => '1842',
            'author' => 10,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Сказка о рыбаке и рыбке',
            'publishedAt' => '1833',
            'author' => 301,
        ],
    ],
];

echo '=== Книги ===<br>';

foreach ($data['books'] as $book) {
    // Проверяем, есть ли у нас вообще такой автор
    if (!array_key_exists($book['author'], $data['authors'])) {
        // Если нет, пропускаем книгу, ну или бросаем исключение и т.д.
        continue;
    }
    $author = $data['authors'][$book['author']]
    echo $book['title'] . ' - ' . $author['name'] . ' - ' . $book['publishedAt'] . '<br>';
}
```

Не понятно зачем вы нагородили такие проверки и захардкодили имена авторов

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!
Только изучаю php, благодаря Вам смог лучше разобраться в работе с массивами.

Comment: А как можно без использования функции?

Comment: без использования какой функции?

Comment: array_key_exists()

Comment: если вы уверены, в массиве авторов точно есть такой ключ, то можно просто удалить весь блок `if`